# How to send 204 No Content with Go http package?

Tags: google-app-engine, http, go

I built a [tiny sample app](https://github.com/jaeckel/go-appengine) with [Go](http://golang.org/) on [Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/index) that sends string responses when different URLs are invoked. But how can I use Go's [http package](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) to send a 204 No Content response to clients?

```
package hello

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "appengine"
    "appengine/memcache"
)

func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", hello)
    http.HandleFunc("/hits", showHits)
}

func hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    name := r.Header.Get("name")
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello %s!", name)
}

func showHits(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "%d", hits(r))
}

func hits(r *http.Request) uint64 {
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)
    newValue, _ := memcache.Increment(c, "hits", 1, 0)
    return newValue
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

According to the package docs:

```
func NoContent(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  // Set up any headers you want here.
  w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNoContent) // send the headers with a 204 response code.
}
```

will send a 204 status to the client.

Comment: You can say `http.StatusNoContent` instead of 204, which is better IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

Sending 204 response from your script means your instance still need to run and cost you money. If you are looking for a caching solution. Google got it and it's called Edge Cache.

You only need to response with the following headers and Google will automatically cache your response in multiple servers nearest to the users (that is, replying with 204). This greatly enhance your site's speed and reduce instance cost.

```
w.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=86400")
w.Header().Set("Pragma", "Public")
```

You can adjust the max-age, but do it wisely.

By the way, it seems billing must be enabled in order to use Edge Cache

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I [added](https://github.com/jaeckel/go-appengine/blob/master/hello.go#L21) [one endpoint](http://ingoingoingo23.appspot.com/no/content/cache) that sets the `Cache-Control` header to 10 seconds. I do not have billing enabled. But I already see that the 1st request in a 10s bucket takes 200-400ms. Subsequent requests in the same 10s bucket take less than 10ms. I can confirm that subsequent requests do not arrive on the app servers by looking at the logs.

Comment: This answer may have misunderstood the purpose of 204. Don't confuse it with 304 ("not modified") which is to avoid duplicate responses being returned. Instead, 204 is an explicit _success_ code where there really is *no content*. You often get these from PUT requests, for example.